# Implement Blind Signature in Foo Protocol

Tags: php, phpseclib, electronic-signature

I'm working on e-voting based on blind-signature ( FOO Schema ), does anyone know how to implement blind signature and unblind it in phpseclib? does phpseclib has function for this? My project only needs one line of code to be complete, please help me.